# Javascript ES5: How to extend the Function object in order to set a property value on itself, every time the function is executed?

Tags: javascript, extending-classes

I currently have the following working code:

```
Function.prototype.GetLastCallerName = function () {
  if (!this.arguments || !this.arguments.callee || !this.arguments.callee.caller) return null;
  var result = /^function\s+([\w\$]+)\s*\(/.exec(this.arguments.callee.caller.toString());
  this.LastCaller = result ? result[1] : 'Anonymous';
  return this.LastCaller;
};
```

I picked up that code from another thread.  As you can see, it extends the Function.prototype in order to add a method called `GetLastCallerName`, which picks the last calling function name and (1) sets it to `LastCaller` on `Function.LastCaller` and (2) returns it.

In order to make it work:

```
function MyFunction1() {
  MyFunction1.GetLastCallerName();
  console.log(MyFunction.LastCaller);
}

function MyFunction2() { 
  MyFunction1(); 
}

MyFunction2();
```

**What I'd like to be able to do**:  Eliminate the need to use `GetLastCallerName()` every time and extend `Function` in order to perform that get every time any function is called.

Comment: ...but why would you want to do this?

Comment: On **any** function? Nope, can't do it in ES5. (You could in ES2015+, but only by doing some Really Horrible Things to `Function.prototype` (or individually to functions, as a one-off) -- and it would still fail in strict mode like `GetLastCallerName` does). Moreover, you **shouldn't** do it. :-) (And shouldn't do the `GetLastCallerName` thing either

Comment: It it not recommended to modify the prototype of native objects. Instead, create an object that inherits from Function and modify that.

Comment: You are also not following proper casing conventions for functions.

Comment: Plus even this code won't work in strict mode. Hello `arguments .callee`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Thank you for your reply... I understand what you're saying and you're right, but this is the only way (for the moment) I've found functional, with the minimal amount of code, to resolve my need.  It simply works, but it depends on having to call that method everytime.

Comment: All good comment, thank you so much for them...gosh, is there any way I can then achieve this? (getting the last calling function's name)

Comment: @Arnie were you able to make any forward progress on this? Was my answer below able to point you in the right direction? Please share some feedback as I'd like to help you solve this!

Comment: @scniro:  My sincere apologies for replying so late! I'm from Puerto Rico and hurricane Maria left us in very bad shape. All communications were down for quite some time and I haven't had the opportunity to log back in.  As to your question:  yes, your answer did partially help.  Problem is that I couldn't use ES6 classes in the project I was working on, so I was looking for a way to achieve the same without using them. The GetLastCaller() extension was only intended for debugging purposes, but finding a way to achieve what I was looking for would prove helpful in the future ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to follow what you have tried so far with your example, but I think I get the idea of what you'd like to do. Why not leverage [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), and [extend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) on them for your use case. Check out the following example...

```
class Base {

  baseFn() {
    console.log('from base');
  }
}

class Thing extends Base {

  fn1() {
    this.baseFn();
  }
}

let thingee = new Thing();

thingee.fn1();
```

So `baseFn` is now always called when `fn1` is called.

[JSFiddle Link - class demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L6bzotr4/)

---

In some of your comments it looks like you are wanting to get the "last calling function's name." How about passing back the instance of the caller itself to the parent? This would surely give you even more flexibility because now you can sculpt your caller however you wish. Check out the following...

```
class Base {

  baseFn(caller) {
    console.log(caller.id); // 1
  }
}

class Thing extends Base {

  constructor(id) {
    super();

    this.id = id;
  }

  fn1() {
    this.baseFn(this);
  }
}

let thingee = new Thing('1');

thingee.fn1();
```

Now you can add whatever you'd like to your `Thing` instance, in this case, an object with an `id` of `1` which can be inspected when `fn1` propagates up to `baseFn`

[JSFiddle Link - caller demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mcn47z8u/)